# Cross-browser method to disable vertical scrolling of window using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable window scrolling when I `mouseover` a specific `div` and enable it on `mouseout`. But it's necessary to keep scrollbars, so `overflow: hidden` will not help.

I wrote a bit of JS, but it's to buggy in IE9 and Opera.

```
var win_scrolltop, is_mydiv_mouseovered = false;
$('#mydiv').hover(
    function(){
        win_scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
        is_mydiv_mouseovered = true;
    },
    function() {
        is_mydiv_mouseovered = false;
    }
)
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (is_mydiv_mouseovered) $(window).scrollTop(win_scrolltop);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) answer, fiddled a little and result is this:

```
var scrollThing = {
    // 33: PageUp, 34: PageDown, 35: End, 36: Home, 37: Left, 38: Up, 39: Right, 40: Down
    keys: [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
    preventDefault: function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        e.returnValue = false;
    },
    keydown: function(e) {
        for (var i = scrollThing.keys.length; i--;) {
            if (e.keyCode === scrollThing.keys[i]) {
                scrollThing.preventDefault(e);
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    disable: function() {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrollThing.preventDefault, false);
        }
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = scrollThing.preventDefault;
        document.onkeydown = scrollThing.keydown;
    },
    enable: function() {
        if (window.removeEventListener) {
            window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrollThing.preventDefault, false);
        }
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;
    }
}
$('#mydiv').hover(scrollThing.disable, scrollThing.enable);
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/arPZX/7/).

Comment: Thanks, but thats swathing in IE and opera too.

Comment: Did you try my example (http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/arPZX/) in IE and Opera? It works. Maybe there is some other error in your code which prevents running this code?

Comment: mousewheel gives bad effect ! you can disable it's action using the mousewheel jquery plugin. is that right ?

Comment: **Emre Erkan** Yes i tried. In IE9 and Opera it's twitches. 
I tryed to use .mousewheel(function(event)...) and event.preventDefault(); but it doesn't works in IE, but works in Opera

Comment: That might stop scrolling using the mouse wheel while hovering over the div, but it doesn't stop scrolling in general. What about touch devices? They don't have a hover event (or mouse wheel event) so the above fails completely.

Comment: I updated my answer. It looks like [there is a better way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) to disable scrolling.

Comment: **Emre Erkan** Thanks! Seems like it works in all browsers, even in IE7!

Comment: **Emre Erkan** There an mistake at 9 line in your code above. There should be an e.returnValue instead of event.returnValue

Comment: Thanks I fixed it. I appreciate if you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243). :)

Comment: This does not work consistently. I'm using Chrome latest as of this comment on latest OS X, and when I scroll whilst I move the pointer out of the browser window viewport, it will scroll the page just as the pointer leaves the browser viewport.